# Perl: Let derived class use modules loaded by base class

Tags: perl

In base class `Base.pm`:

```
 package Base;
 use Modern::Perl;

 sub new {
     return bless {}, shift;
 }

 sub hi {
     say 'hi from base class';
 }

 1;
```

In derived class `Derived.pm`:

```
 package Derived;
 use parent Base;

 sub hi {
     say 'hi from derived class';
 }

 1;
```

In `main.pl`:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env perl

 use Derived;

 my $d = Derived->new;

 $d->hi;
```

There's an error when running `main.pl`:

```
String found where operator expected at Derived.pm line 5, near "say 'hi from derived class'"
        (Do you need to predeclare say?)
syntax error at Derived.pm line 5, near "say 'hi from derived class'"
Compilation failed in require at ./main.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./main.pl line 3.
```

Seems like `Modern::Perl` is not being imported by derived class.

It can be solved by explicitly `use Modern::Perl` in derived class, but I'd like to reduce such boilerplate code.

How to make derived class use modules of base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use modules wherever they're needed, except for base classes of object-oriented modules.

It would be unnecessarily awkward if `use Base` included *everything* that the base class used whether or not it was necessary or appropriate.

Comment: +1, though technically I think `Base::import` can choose to export stuff that `Base` had imported, and could be selective about it.

Comment: But base class includes _everything_ that subclass needed. Type same modules in derived classed over and over is not fun.

Comment: @Kai-HengFeng: And suppose the base class included only *some* of what the subclass needed, plus a *lot* of huge modules that it didn't need that would break the subclass. How is Perl supposed to infer what to include and what to leave out?

Comment: @Kai-HengFeng: By the way, I strongly discourage the use of `Modern::Perl`, as it is far from clear what it does without reading the documentation. `use strict` and `use warnings` is all that is necessary except in some unusual situations, and it should appear at the start of *every* program.

Comment: @ruakh: But `use` is about more than importing symbols. Pragmas (and, despite its name, `Modern::Perl` falls into that class) change the programming context in many other ways.

Comment: @Borodin: You are right. It's not sane to import everything from base class to derived class. But what should I do to reduce boilerplate when I use same modules across different derived classes?

Comment: If your boilerplate is just one or two lines then I wouldn't have thought it was a problem. If you have a *lot* of boilerplate then please show an example.

Comment: You could use `do 'boilerplate.pl'`, as that works like a C `#include`, but I really wouldn't like to see that in code I was debugging.

Comment: @Borodin: I'm not so sure. `strict` and `Modern::Perl` are pragmas, yes, but they're implemented as normal `.pm` files with clever `import` functions. (They take advantage of the special scoping behavior of variables like `$^H`, which of course were designed for this purpose.) `Modern::Perl->import`, for example, includes the lines `warnings->import` and `strict->import`. So while I haven't tested, I'm pretty confident that `Base::import` could simply include the line `Modern::Perl->import` in order to have all includers of `Base` implicitly `use Modern::Perl`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have boilerplate `use` statements (pragmas, imports, etc) that you wish to import into all your classes, I'd look at something like [Syntax::Collector](https://metacpan.org/pod/Syntax%3a%3aCollector) to handle it.

**MyApp/Syntax.pm**

```
package MyApp::Syntax;
use Syntax::Collector -collect => q{
use Modern::Perl 2013;
use List::Util 1.35 qw( first any all reduce );
use Scalar::Util 1.35 qw( blessed weaken );
};
1;
```

**MyApp/Base.pm**

```
package MyApp::Base;
use MyApp::Syntax;
...;
1;
```

**MyApp/Derived.pm**

```
package MyApp::Derived;
use MyApp::Syntax;
use parent "MyApp::Base";
...;
1;
```

Comment: Does `Syntax::Collector` has something like "use latest version"? It's really close to what I want.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "use latest version"? Where it says `use List::Util 1.35` it will use a later version of List::Util if it's installed. The `1.35` part is the *minimum required version*.

Answer (score 0):

`say` is enabled by `Modern::Perl`, but it isn't exported by it. It's a Perl command that has to be enabled (see [say](http://p3rl.org/say)) or preceded with `CORE::` in order to be recognised by the Perl parser.

Comment: So I have to type `use Modern::Perl` in every derived class?

Comment: @Kai-HengFeng: Or use `CORE::say` instead of `say`.